# "open_account" is not defined error/variables not working

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello so my issue is the code works perfectly fine within the main.py file but as soon as
I try to convert it into a cog all of my variables stop working. I'm sure this is a stupid fix but learning is learning :D

```
        class Economy(commands.Cog):
    
        def __init__(self, client):
            self.client = client
    
        @commands.command(aliases = ['money', 'cash', 'bal'])
        async def balance(self, ctx):
            await open_account(ctx.author)
            user = ctx.author
            users = await get_bank_data()
    
            wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
            bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
    
            em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color = discord.Color.red())
            em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance",value = wallet_amt)
            em.add_field(name = "Bank balance",value = bank_amt)
            await ctx.send(embed = em)
    
        @commands.command(aliases = ['take', 'draw',])
        async def withdraw(self, ctx, amount = None):
            await open_account(ctx.author)
    
            if amount == None:
                await ctx.send("Please enter the amount")
                return
    
            bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
    
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount>bal[1]:
                await ctx.send("You don't have that much money!")
                return
            if amount<0:
                await ctx.send("Amount must be positive!")
                return
    
            await update_bank(ctx.author,amount)
            await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount, "bank")
            await ctx.send(f"You withdrew {amount} coins")
    

    def setup(client):
        client.add_cog(Economy(client))
```

Comment: Are your `open_account` and `get_bank_data` functions inside your cog as well? Your code won't work if it isn't.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation on your code? Also, could you clarify what you mean by having variables stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little poking and messing with it, I wasn't passing "self" into my paras.

All solved now but I'll give an example in case anyone has the same issue.

```
@commands.command(aliases = ['money', 'cash', 'bal'])
async def balance(self,ctx):
    self.bot = self
    await self.open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await self.get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance",value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank balance",value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

basically if anyone runs into the same issue remember to always use "self." and to define it if necessary.